# Java SQL simple update syntax issue

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, sql-update

I have a table named **books** with bookID, bookName, count , orderCount

i'd like to write an sql query that will update all books.orderCount to books.orderCount+1.

How shall i do that using `executeQuery("UPDATE books....");` ?
I'm having troubles with the syntax.

I've tried to search info on the net however most articles are about INSERT or DELETE commands and the only article that was related suggested to retrieve orderCount to Java, update it and then write it back to SQL. if possible i prefer to avoid it as it may cause serious problems (Locks on records are not needed for this task so i can not use them to avoid problems)

Comment: you should use `executeUpdate` instead of `executeQuery` as it returns some 'statistics' about the number of rows updates. The Database drivers might further optimze this kind of statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this should be pretty straight forward,

```
UPDATE books 
SET orderCount = orderCount + 1
```

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe i wasted a whole hours on that :)

Answer (score 0):

If it's about a `primary key:`

Also, you can AUTO INCREMENT.

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
 (
 P_Id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 FirstName varchar(255),
 Address varchar(255),
 City varchar(255),
 PRIMARY KEY (P_Id)
 )
```

To let the AUTO_INCREMENT sequence start with another value, use the following SQL statement:

```
ALTER TABLE Persons AUTO_INCREMENT=100
```

To insert a new record into the "Persons" table, we will not have to specify a value for the "P_Id" column (a unique value will be added automatically):

```
INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName,LastName)
VALUES ('Lars','Monsen')
```

Comment: Oh yes truely agree.It is only applicable to Primary key.Just trying to add somethin to above answer.Will make an update.

Comment: NP, nevertheless, It recommend to delete the answer as it does not help to solve the OPs problem. Have fun.